# JS onpaste event should run a code and not paste

Tags: javascript

I have a code that I want to run whenever a paste event is being triggered on the page.

The code should take all the data from the clipboard and should paste it value by value in different fields in the form.

The issue is that the first field, where the paste event is being done, gets all the values instead of the first of the list.
All the other fields in the Form get populated correctly.

Pls find attached the code and a screenshot,

thanks for your help

```
document.addEventListener('paste', e=>{
    let data = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    let id = e.target.id;
    let id_ex = id.slice(0,2);
    var fill_array =[];
    var line = Number(id.slice(2,4));
    
  if (id_ex == "SK" || "DE" || "QT"){

    var splitter = data.split(/\r?\n/);
    var len = splitter.length;
  
    for (i=0;i<len;i++){
  
        if(splitter[i] == ""){}

          else{fill_array.push(splitter[i]);}
          }
    

    for (q=0;q<fill_array.length;q++){
      var lin = line + q;
      var id_to_fill = id_ex+lin  ;
      document.getElementById(id_to_fill).value = fill_array[q];
    }
  
    document.getElementById(id).value = fill_array[0];
   }



  else{}

});
```

[image]

Comment: Please pride a sample of the clipboard content or provide markup that can be copied to produce content.

Comment: hi Yogi, the data that I pasted comes from a single column in Excel, , copying data from eg A1 to A20, and then pasting in the form, meaning I want to copy a column in excel and paste it in the column in the form where I inicaited the paste event.
The issue is that it works correctly, only it als ocopies all the data in the field where I triggered the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent `paste` action you should `event.preventDefault()`

```
document.addEventListener('paste', e => {
   if ( !isEventIDoHandle(e) ) return; // will paste
   e.preventDefault(); // will not paste
   handlePasteEventAsIWant(e);
})
```